# Gparted did not change home partition size as expected

Tags: partitioning, gparted

```
Ubutnu 18.04.16 Server running on a ESXI VM standalone server.
df -Th
Filesystem                       Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                             devtmpfs   16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            tmpfs     3.2G  2.8M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/INMLDSERV01--vg-root ext4       11G  8.3G  1.8G  83% /
tmpfs                            tmpfs      16G  1.1M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                            tmpfs      16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                       squashfs  117M  117M     0 100% /snap/core/1478                                             4
/dev/loop1                       squashfs  9.7M  9.7M     0 100% /snap/canonical                                             -livepatch/209
/dev/loop2                       squashfs  9.7M  9.7M     0 100% /snap/canonical                                             -livepatch/202
/dev/loop3                       squashfs  117M  117M     0 100% /snap/core/1494                                             6
/dev/loop4                       squashfs   18M   18M     0 100% /snap/pdftk/9
/dev/sdb1                        ext4      493G  142G  326G  31% /mnt/APPDATA
/dev/mapper/INMLDSERV01--vg-home ext4       20G  4.8G   14G  26% /home
/dev/sda1                        ext2      472M   82M  366M  19% /boot
tmpfs                            tmpfs     3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Trying to increase home directory so I have enough room to do-release-upgrade.  (It is the Home directories that need more space right?  Most explanations don't make that clear.)
Able to boot Gparted ISO.  I grew /sd2 and /sd5 to maximum (well after the third time of nothing happening).

Gparted screen:
[image]

Nothing changes on my Ubuntu VM.  Everything is backed up.

Comment: It looks like you have used LVM (and possibly LUKS encryption) when you installed Ubuntu. You will need to resize the LVM which resides inside `/dev/sda5`, which resides inside `/dev/sda2`. Within the LVM you will need to expand the `/dev/mapper/INMLDSERV01--vg-root` **not the home**.

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04) had 5 years of *standard* support life, is nearing the end of those five years. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm if your system is still *supported*. Either way, if the machine is on-line, you should plan to *release-upgrade* asap unless you plan to use ESM/Pro, but please note ESM/Pro releases are not on-topic here when standard support ends.   *Also check your details; you're not using an actual valid OS given your details unless typo*